# Ckeditor changes <button> tags to <p> tag

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

Trying to get a button working in content item but ckeditor won't let me.

I tried pasting in source. But when toggling back and forth bewteen source and rich text editor the html changes.

Goes from:

```
<button>click</button>
```

To

```
<p>click</p>
```

I've tried:

```
<p><button>click</button></p>
```

Not working either.

This never happened before, a settings thing?

Comment: You sure it is CKEditor and not your text format filters?

Comment: Just to understand: Are we talking about a site where Drupal has been upgraded (e.g. from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8)? I am referring to your _This never happened before._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is  Drupal bug that has been around for years, not even fixed in Drupal 8.

I deleted a text format, disable = delete, not disable, only way to get it back is through PHPmy admin and set to true and false...

Solution:

DON'T TOUCH TEXT FORMATS!

Anybody correct me if I'm wrong, but that's the conclusion I came to.

Answer (score 2):

For **FILTER HTML** go to:

> /admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html

add `<button>` to the limit allowed HTML Tags list.

[image]

If you use **FULL HTML** the button should work.

### **If not try**

go to:

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced (for Filter HTML)

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full (for Full HTML)

Then under Advanced Content Filter, select disabled.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work in ANY text format, no matter what settings I use

Comment: @BrunoVincent updated my answer.

Comment: It would be helpful if the OP would make clear what _This never happened before._ means. It seems strange that, without changing settings, the result changes, except if a module was installed/updated. If the settings were changed, they must be one of the ones listed in this answer.

Comment: Deleting a text format started this behavior. Thank you for trying to help

Comment: @BrunoVincent that's weird, but good to hear that you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

U will have to change above settings, for all text format like: filtered_html, full_html. After that clear your website cache, and it will work.

> /admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html
>
> /admin/config/content/formats/full_html

Comment: I went and edited all formats to the settings above, one change I DID do in the past while was delete a text format, because disable doesn't disable, it deletes them, that's a  bug I read about. How can I delete all text formats and reset the original ones? I think something might have gotten corrupted.